# Hibernate sequence id generator value population

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have a DO in java that has one field that is a generated value using GenerationType.SEQUENCE and I want to create a new instance of this object will the field be automatically populated?  I.e.

```
public class LogEntry {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ENTITY_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ENTITY_SEQ")
@Column(name = "migration_batch_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 38)
private long uniqueId;

//Bunch of other fields
}
```

If I create an instance of a LogEntry class, set other fields, then save the instance to the database.  Will the uniqueId field be set automatically?

Comment: What is the status of your question @thurmc? You didn't accepted an answer. Are you still in doubt - do you still have a question? Can you please ask in that case?

Answer (score 0):

It will be set after `EntityManager.merge(entityObject)` or `EntityManager.persist(entityObject)`. Be aware that the first returns the entity with the id and the second sets the id in the specified entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be set automatically, but since you are using sequence as generation type, and sequences are created at the database end, so until this object which is saved as an entry in DB, you will not get an the sequence value generated. Point i am trying to make is that the object needs to be flushed. As long as hibernate fired a query to do an insert of this object, you will have this id set.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the solution was to also provide sequence_name to sequence generator annotation